# Android Google Maps search by keywords

Tags: android, maps, keyword

I have a problem of keywords composing in query. I need to make a query which will search, for example, by "spord doctor" or "doctors" or "medicine" in one query (&keywod="sport doctor"|"medicine"|"sport"|"doctor". This query is not working but how to do this one correcly). I cannot compose it in one query. Are there any solution how to do it because in the documentation I see only one example where is a search by one keyword or phrase. Finally I want to do one long query where is "sport doctors" on different languages.

I have found the solution. But it is working in the browser URL bar, not in the app. I used pipe "|" as OR statement in the query: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=59.436347,24.752356&radius=34572.53586&keyword=spordiarst|sport&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCEVB4rY2A_AEyJ5JeopxaGz4zqm47yLuY

But I have error in the app if I put something like this:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?" + 
            "location=" + ((lat == 0 || lat == gpsLat) ? gpsLat : lat) + ","+ ((lon == 0 || lon == gpsLon) ? gpsLon : lon) +
            "&radius=" + radius +
            "&keyword=\"spordiarst\"|\"sport\"" +
            "&types=establishment" +
            "&sensor=false&" +
            "key=" + GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY);
```

Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 127: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=59.435330809999996,24.7727237&radius=1404.114013671875&keyword="spordiarst"|"sport"&types=establishment&sensor=false&key=HERE IS MY KEY

How to fix it? As I see there is no spaces and something specific symbols but it crashes. It seems that it appears due to pipe "|" or double quotes \".

Comment: Please add a link to the API documentation you use. At least I'm not sure what kind of google maps search it is.

Comment: I used this documentation with json output format: https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/additional-places-features

Comment: I have found the solution. But it is working in the browser URL bar, not in the app. I used pipe "|" as OR statement in the query: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=59.436347,24.752356&radius=34572.53586&keyword=spordiarst|sport&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCEVB4rY2A_AEyJ5JeopxaGz4zqm47yLuY

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [URLEncoding](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
String types = "restaurant|food";
try {
     types = URLEncoder.encode(types, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

User this encoder to make pipe work with HttpGet, otherwise you will get Illegar Character exception